# How to approach SVG with dimensions

Tags: svg, vector-graphics

I am wanting to draw a basketball court to scale in an SVG image.

I have the [dimensions of the court](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basketball_court#Dimensions).

**How can I create the SVG image using dimensions from real-life and have the output be proportionately scaled down to fit in an arbitrary image size such as 300px by 300px?**

**EDIT**: to clarify more - I want to draw the paint lines, which are 5 inches in real life.  Do I make 5 inches my "unit" and then multiply everything else by this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving frameworks like Raphael aside, couldn't you draw the whole court inside a `<svg height="50" width="94">` (or use inches as your unit), then enclose the whole thing inside a `<g transform="scale(3.14159)">` scaling it up or down to fit the 300 pixels?  There are a large variety of transforms available for the `<g>` element.  SVG is really good at this kind of thing, and you could use familiar measures in your root drawing.

Answer (score 0):

If a basketball court is 94 ft long and you want to draw it to scale to fit within 300px, then figure out the proportions based on your target size.  300 / 94 = 3.19.  Use that number to decide your scale (including the width of the paint lines).

Comment: Where I am getting stuck is - you did 94 ft divided by 300 px... to get paint line width, which is in inches, I would multiply (5/12) * 3.19 ?

Comment: I would probably calculate all dimensions in inches.  That would make it easier.  (94 * 12) / 300 = 3.76.  Then you'd divide all your dimensions in inches by 3.76.  5in = 1.33px.  You could possible draw the whole thing using 1:1 on inches to pixels, and then scale it.  Are you using a framework or library for this?  I really like Raphaeljs.

Comment: I am using cairo actually - not particularly tied to it though so I could end up using another svg library.  Thanks for your help, I plan on testing this out later today

Comment: Glad to help.  I'll have to check out cairo.  So many cool libraries and frameworks out there, and too little time...